# jax-rs plugin custom serializer and deserializer

Tags: jax-rs

is there a way in jax-rs to plugin custom serializer and deserializer,

This is kind of important to migrate some of the existing consumers to REST world.

Comment: What jax-rs implementation are you using?  CXF?  Jersey?

Comment: I am using jersey implementation of jax-rs

Answer (score 0):

You should define a custom [Provider](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers.html) with message body readers/writers:

> Entity providers supply serialization and/or deserialization services between resource representations and their associated Java types. An entity provider that supports deserialization of a representation to a Java type implements the MessageBodyReader interface. An entity provider that supports serialization of a Java type to a representation implements the MessageBodyWriter interface.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jax-rs-159890.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but when i have consumer from SOA and REST existing together, i want request and response from the REST client shouldn't be disturbed, but referring http://java.boot.by/ocewsd6-guide/ch02.html what i feel is that, i need to code up MessageBodyReader considering both ....is it not possible to say that apply this MessageBodyReader only in a type of client ( based on HTTP header ) and other wise follow normal routine.